# vanilla js image fader not working at all, any ideas?

Tags: javascript

can anyone help me spot the bug in this code? it should fade out the box but its not doing anything. basically I'm using a setinverval to call the function fadeout every 50ms, the fadeout function reduces the opacity of the element by .05 every run through, checking each time that if it is equal to or less than 0, then clear interval

html

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner" id="one"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#container{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
}

.inner{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

#one {
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color:rgba(100,100,100,1);
}
```

js

```
var c = document.getElementById("one");

function fade(){
  if (!c.style.opacity){
     c.style.opacity = 1;
  };

var interval = setInterval (fadeout, 50);

function fadeout(){
    c.style.opacity -= .05;

    if (c.style.opacity <= 0){
       clearInterval(interval);
       };
    };
};
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `fade` function?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call your `fade()` function

```js
var c = document.getElementById("one");

function fade() {
  if (!c.style.opacity) {
    c.style.opacity = 1;
  };

  var interval = setInterval(fadeout, 50);

  function fadeout() {
    c.style.opacity -= .05;

    if (c.style.opacity <= 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  };
};

fade();
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#one {
  left: 25px;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(100, 100, 100, 1);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="inner" id="one"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @busso upvotes or answer acceptance is much appreciated.